# Dígitos em uma string java

Tags: java, string

Como faço para descobrir quantos dígitos tem uma String em java ?
Por exemplo, usuário entrou com "exemplo123", a string tem 3 dígitos.
Estou usando esta função mas não está funcionando:

```
private static int digitos(String text) {
        char[] digitos = new char[9];
        int digitosTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i != 9; i++) {
            digitos[i] = (char) i;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < digitos.length; i++) {
            if (text.indexOf(digitos[i]) != -1) {
                digitosTotal++;
            }
        }
        return digitosTotal;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode descobrir quantos dígitos existem na string pode iterar ela e comparar o código ascii de cada elemento, caso ele esteja na faixa de 48 e 57 é um número.

[**Exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/tAXnuU)

**[Wikipedia - tabela ascii](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String text = "Digito123";

        char[] digitos = new char[9];
        int digitosTotal = 0;

        for(char caracter : text.toCharArray()){
            int asciiCode = (int)caracter;
            if(asciiCode >= 48 &&  asciiCode <= 57) digitosTotal++;
        }

        System.out.print(digitosTotal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dá pra trocar `48` por `'0'` e `57` por `'9'`.

Comment: @Piovezan legal :D não sabia disso.

Comment: @Piovezan quando vc faz `if(asciiCode >= '0') ..` o `'0'` é convertido para automáticamente para 48, seria isso?

Comment: Eu não sei em que passo o Java faz isso, acho que é na análise léxica. Mas o caracter que estiver entre as aspas simples é convertido para seu valor Unicode (se não estou enganado). Também dá para entrar códigos \u0048 por exemplo mas eu não estou acostumado a usá-los.

Comment: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/andru/javaspec/3.doc.html

Comment: @rray, um caracter em Java é um tipo numérico. Então, '0' é considerado o caracter 0, que tem valor 0x30

Answer (score 4):

Utilizando o método isDigit da classe Character     [**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/99tetu)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        String text = "Digito123";

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0, len = text.length(); i < len; i++) {
          if (Character.isDigit(text.charAt(i))) {
           count++;
          }
        }

        System.out.print(count);

    }
}
```

> O método charAt mostra-se mais rápido (Success #stdin #stdout 0.04s 4386816KB) do que o método toCharArray (Success #stdin #stdout 0.06s 2841600KB)

Answer (score 3):

```
String str = "123123asdasdas" ;
String aux = str;
aux = aux .replaceAll("\\D+","");
System.out.println("Quantidade de dígitos: " + aux .length());
```

Comment: Não quero deletar, quero saber quantos dígitos tem

Comment: Editado meu caro, não tinha necessidade de dar um negativo.

Comment: Estava procurando por exatamente essa resposta para dar um +1! Seu uso de expressões é admirável

Answer (score 3):

Pode utilizar expressão regular para contar o número de dígitos e para extraí-los do texto, caso for necessário:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Total de dígitos:
    int count = 0;

    // Lista de dígitos:
    List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // Expressão regular para obter um dígito:
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d");

    // Texto a ser analisado:
    Matcher m = p.matcher("exemplo123");

    // Conta quantos dígitos há no texto:
    while (m.find())
    {
      // Incrementa a quantidade de dígitos:
      count++;

      // Insere o dígito na lista:
      digits.add(new Integer(m.group()));
    }

    // Exibe o total:
    System.out.println(count);

    // Exibe a lista de dígitos:
    System.out.println(digits);

  }

}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/IcIm9h).

A saída do código é:

```
3
[1, 2, 3]
```

Onde `3` indica a quantidade de dígitos e `[1, 2, 3]` a lista dos mesmos.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int contaDigitos(String arg) {
    int nums = 0;
    for(char ch : arg.toCharArray()){
        if(Character.isDigit(ch)) nums++;
    }
    return nums;
}
```